# Element type is invalid with react-leaflet in react jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-leaflet

I'm trying to use jest to test whether the link in the document but the test was failed  with an invalid element type. Why is import from "react-leaflet" turns out to be undefined in jest?

My test

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(
    <App />
  )
  const linkElement = screen.getByText("map-btn");
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

And the App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap, Circle } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet'

function App(){

    return (
      <div className={'col-md-8'}>
        <div>
          <MapContainer center={[25.033671, 121.564427]} zoom={17} style={{height: '100vh'}} >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={[25.033671, 121.564427]}>
            <Popup>current position</Popup>
          </Marker>
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

[image]

Comment: Did you managed to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost identical setup. What solved it for me was installing the `jest-canvas-mock` module, and then including it in my `src/setupTest.js` file like so:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import 'jest-canvas-mock';
```

I was then able to mock out the actual div containing my `react-leaflet` component used in my application and test that the app did render correctly:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '../src/test-utils';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('./components/MapComponent', () => () =><div>MapComponentMock</div>);

test('renders the app', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const headerLogo = screen.getByAltText(/logo/i);
  expect(headerLogo).toBeInTheDocument();

  const searchButton = screen.getByRole('button', {name: /search/i});
  expect(searchButton).toBeInTheDocument();

});
```